# What is the most common verb for "to introduce."

Tags: translation, english-to-german

As in, "I want to introduce him to her."

Comment: Hint: There are [dictionaries](http://dict.leo.org/dictQuery/m-vocab/ende/en.html?tolerMode=nof&lp=ende&lang=en&rmWords=off&search=introduce&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on), they even include typical phrases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common verb would be *vorstellen*. So in other words

> "I want to introduce him to her."

would translate to

> "Ich möchte ihn ihr vorstellen."

Comment: You could also say "Ich möchte sie bekannt machen." sie = the two people

Comment: @iris... I would add "miteinander" to that. "Bekannt machen" needs a target ("mit" ) in my opinion.

Comment: I think "Ich möchte sie einander vorstellen" would work better than "Ich möchte sie [miteinander] bekannt machen"... at least it sounds better...

Comment: @Emanuel, stimmt "Ich möchte sie miteinander bekannt machen" ist besser.

Comment: @Viking: "Ich möchte sie einander vorstellen" ginge auch. Nur "Ich möchte ihn ihr vorstellen." finde ich, klingt sehr holprig.